# Convert Chrome network request body preview to valid json

Tags: json, network-programming, request, google-chrome-devtools

**My Question:** I want a way to take the preview content (see image below) from Chrome Developer Tools and copy it as valid JSON rather than having to convert it into valid JSON.

[image: Example]

**My Situation:** I'm going to be inspecting a lot of requests on a website and taking the request body as JSON and using that in another part of a project I'm working on. I don't want to have to reconstruct the JSON. I know there are other ways I could perform the requests, but I'd rather just use the website normally and then find all the requests as I go rather then execute the requests on my own. So I'd really like to be able to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that the preview tab is a preview of the response rather than the request body. To get that as json text you just click the response tab and it will show you the response body. If you want the request body you look at the headers tab. In some cases it will just be form data.

Comment: In a request just Ctrl+C it with key, the right mouse click does not indicates a thing.

Answer (score 1):

To get preview of any object the same way it looks in the Developer tools: Right click on the object you wish to copy and select "Copy Object". You can paste it in your notepad++ and it gives you the data you require in valid JSON format.[CopyObject_FromPreview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8sWV.png)